# How do I revoke a Salesforce.com token from a .NET app

Tags: c#, login-errors

This should be easy, but it isn't. I have a .NET app were users sign in to salesforce.com using REST, logging in works fine, I'm getting back the session Id and proceed without problems. But when the user wants to log out and clicks the logout button - I'm not able to log him/her out. According to [this article](http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2011/11/revoking-oauth-2-0-access-tokens-and-refresh-tokens.html)
I simply need to send a post request to https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/revoke

Here's what I'm doing in my code:

```
using (var wb = new WebClient())
{
   string server = "https://login.salesforce.com/";            
   var data = new NameValueCollection();
   data["token"] = sForceService.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId;
   var response = wb.UploadValues(server + "services/oauth2/revoke", "POST", data);
}
```

This code always throws a (400) Bad Request Web Exception. There's no description in the exception, so I have no idea what's going on.
I also tried an alternative code that specifies content-type as 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' to do the POST (see below), but the result is the same... It must be something simple that I'm missing...

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(server +"services/oauth2/revoke");
request.Method = "POST";
string postData = "token="+sForceService.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId;
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream.Close();
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
reader.Close();
dataStream.Close();
response.Close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the end of the [article](http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2011/11/revoking-oauth-2-0-access-tokens-and-refresh-tokens.html) you link to:

> Also, note that, currently, **only tokens issued by OAuth can be revoked in this way; an attempt to revoke a session ID issued by SOAP login() or as a sid cookie will fail**. A future release will allow all tokens to be revoked via the OAuth 2.0 endpoint, regardless of their issuing mechanism.

So you can't currently pass a SessionId to revoke. It needs to be an OAuth token.

Instead, you can send a SOAP [`logout()`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_logout.htm) request for the current session ID (the sessionId will go in the [SessionHeader](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_header_sessionheader.htm)).

Comment: that's what I'm doing, the user presses logout and I send SOAP logout(). However, when the user presses Login again, and I'm opening login.salesforce.com in a browser control - it automatically logs in for him, so there's actually no way to, say, switch the current user. I thought this was happening because the current token is still active... But maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: Since you are sending them to a browser control I assume you are using one of the oauth flows to ultimately get the SessionId? Try holding onto the access_token that is returned by the authentication response and then using that to revoke access. Failing that, are there any browser cookies that need to be cleared?

Comment: Yeah, but access_token is exactly what I assign to sForceService.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId during login. Afterwards it works great as the session Id. But when I try to log out with it - it doesn't work. As for the cookie, I thought about it too, but I can't blindly reset all of them as it will also reset them for the system browser. Also, somehow when I press logout on the SFDC site and then go back to login.salesforce.com - it doesn't log me in automatically, the only time it'll log me in automatically on the site is if the token has not been revoked. Very confusing stuff...

Comment: I just tried doing SOAP logout() and it actually works, the session becomes invalid. However, I'm still wondering why when I navigate the user to login.salesforce.com after logout, sfdc logs him/her in automatically... Going to ask it in a separate thread.